# na.rm is not found in R

Tags: r, function, na.rm

I am trying to use na.rm but it looks like it is not in R at all. I was using it in the past just now it does not seem to be there at all. I tried using the help() function and the ??na.rm both showed not results. How could this suddenly happen? and how do I get it back?

thank you

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: You should share your code snippet in R as na.rm is still exist.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just confusing the function `na.omit` and the argument `na.rm` that is in many base functions?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `na.rm` is not a function for you to call. It is an argument that is used inside some built-in functions such as `mean()`, `sd()`, `var()` etc. If you want to remove missing (`NA` values) from a data set (vector, matrix, data frame, tibble etc.) you may use `na.omit` for it is a base function. See the example below:

```
x <- c(2, 3, 5, NA, 5, NA)
mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 3.75
```

As you can see, the mean of `x` vector is calculated excluding the missing values.